# How can I get data from a bootstrap form with dynamicall generated fields and field names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap form in a mern app where users can enter a style (of martial arts), like judo, bjj, etc.  I'm using react-tag-component to add the styles.

When the user enters a style it is added to an array called selected.

I am looping through the selected array and adding the same fiels for each selected style.  So if I enter judo and bjj I get the fields rank and weightClass for each.

The selected array creates 2 fields value and label. The values in the above cases are 0, and 1 and the labels are judo and bjj.

I used onChange to send the value to and inputData object and it works but I cannot figure out how to get the data out.

I tried setting the name={`rank${item.label}`} so I get rankjudo and rankbjj.  I did the same for weightClass.

If I console.log(inputData.rankJudo) I get my rank, but I'm trying to loop through the selected array so I can create a single array with the selected style and the corresponding rank and weightclass.

I have tried rank: `${inputData.rank}${item.label}` but I get undefinedjudo and undefinedbjj in the rank field of the new array called styles. I get the same result with rank: inputData.rank + item.label.

My hope is to end with the style array looking something like:

```
[
 { 
   styleName: "judo",
   rank: "Yellow Belt",
   weightClass: "73kg"
 },
 {
   styleName: "bjj",
   rank: "blue belt",
   weightClass: "165lbs",
 }
]
```

Here is the form:

```
<Form id="myForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Row>
    <Col className="d-flex flex-column my-2">
      <ReactTags
        labelText="Select Style/Sport"
        selected={selected}
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onAdd={onAdd}
        onDelete={onDelete}
        allowNew
        isDisabled={selected.length > 0}
        placeholderText="Add Style/Sport"
      />
    </Col>
  </Row>
  {selected &&
    selected.length > 0 &&
      selected.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.value}>
          <Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="validationCustom01">
              <Form.Label>{`My rank in ${item.label}`}</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name={`rank${item.label}`}
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Enter rank in ${item.label}`}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="validationCustom01">
            <Form.Label>{`My primary weight class in ${item.label}`}</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              name={`weightClass${item.label}`}
              type="text"
              placeholder={`Enter weight class in ${item.label}`}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Row>
      </div>
    ))}

  <Button type="submit" className="login_btn">
    Add Style/Sport
 </Button>
</Form>
```

And here are the handleChange and handleSubmit functiosn:

```
const handleChange = (HTMLInputElement) => {
    const { name, value } = HTMLInputElement.target;
    setInputData((prevInputData) => ({ ...prevInputData, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e.target.value);
    let styles = [];

    if (selected) {
      selected.map((item) =>
        styles.push({
          rank: inputData.rank + item.label,
          weightClass: inputData.weightClass + item.label,
        })
      );
    }
    console.log("styles ", styles);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]
The Solution at the bottom whtat I have labeled ORIGINAL worked as long as I entered the data in the form in the order it was listed.  Becase of the onChange{handleChange} which put the data into the inputDate array, if I did them out of order or went back and changed something it would put things in a different order.  So I would get random data in each field since I was just going from looping through and getting each item in the order listed but had no way to contorl the order.

My new solution is actually easier but still might be the best solution, but it actually works no matter the order of if the users changes data before submit.

I used filter to get the entry from the newInput array that has rank + style/sport, so then I push that value to the styles array:

```
const rank = newInputData.filter((string) =>
  string.includes(`rank${item.value}`)
);
```

I also changed the input elements names to {`rank${item.value`} rather than {`rank${item.label`}, so it would be rank0 and weightClass0.

So, now I don't depend on the order, I get styleName from selected then get the rank, promotionDate (added that field), and weightClass based on the styleName.
Here is the whole solution:

```
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState([]);

let handleChange = (HTMLInputElement) => {
  const { name, value } = HTMLInputElement.target;
  setInputData((prevInputData) => ({ ...prevInputData, [name]: value }));
};

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newInputData = Object.entries(inputData);
  let styles = [];
  if (selected) {
    selected.map((item) => {
      const rank = newInputData.filter((string) =>
        string.includes(`rank${item.value}`)
      );
      const promotionDate = newInputData.filter((string) =>
        string.includes(`promotionDate${item.value}`)
      );
      const weightClass = newInputData.filter((string) =>
        string.includes(`weightClass${item.value}`)
      );
      styles.push({
        styleName: item.label,
        rank: rank[0][1],
        promotionDate: promotionDate[0][1],
        weightClass: weightClass[0][1],
      });
    });
  }
}
```

ORIGINAL
I found a few sources that help, with a combination lots of trial and error, I was able to get it to work.  The form is the same but what I ended up doing is creating a new array of objects from the inputData.

I did that with

```
const newInputData = Object.entries(inputData);
```

Then when mapping through the select array I had to institute a count starting at 0 but then at the end of each iteration I had to increase the count by 2 because the newInputData displayed as:

```
(8) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ['rankJudo', 'Rokudan']
1: (2) ['weightClassJudo', '73kg']
2: (2) ['rankbjj', 'blue belt']
3: (2) ['weightClassbjj', '175lbs']
4: (2) ['rankWrestling', 'No rank']
5: (2) ['weightClassWrestling', '155lbs']
6: (2) ['rankrandom sport', 'random rank']
7: (2) ['weightClassrandom sport', 'random weight']
```

So, to push everything into the styles array I got the styleName from selected then got the rank and weightClass from the newInput Data.

Here is what the whole thing looks like:

```
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newInputData = Object.entries(inputData);

    let styles = [];
    if (selected) {
      let count = 0;
      selected.map((item) => {
        styles.push({
          styleName: item.label,
          rank: newInputData[count][1],
          weightClass: newInputData[count + 1][1],
        });
        console.log(count);
        count = count + 2;
      });
    }
}
```

Definitely not the most elegant solution, but it works.  I won't accept the answer for a while, so if someone comes up with a cleaner/better solution I'll give you credit.